# Auto Update query

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to know whether i can direct update mysql datas to add (+) the values, without needing to fetch them.

For example:

My database is like this,
**data1 = 56**
so to add a 4 to it, i will first fetch the data from the database then,

**$data1 = $data1 + 4;**
and finally again perform a Update query.

So is there is way i can send like add +4 to the current value of data1.

I am using php lanuage.

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like... this?

```
UPDATE
  MyTable
SET
  Data = Data + 4
WHERE
  Myid = 123
```

A look into [basic SQL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html) seems advisable. ;-)

If you are working with PHP to manipulate your data, a deeper look into the mysqli_* functions family in general and prepared/parameterized statements in particular is advisable as well.

Comment: sorry for once i thought this kind of thing dont exists, so i didnt looked in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `mytable` SET `data1` = `data1` + 4");
```

You'll want a `WHERE` clause unless you want to update every row.